# What is the meaning of this error message in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, error-handling, simulink, sample-rate

Upon execution of a Simulink model, I received following error:

> The sample time propagated to
>   '[...]/Discrete-Time Integrator' is not discrete
>   but [0, 1]. Specify a discrete sample time in the source of the
>   incoming signal.

Where can I find documentation about this error?

(I cannot post my model due to copyright restrictions. If needed, I will provide an MWE.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read up about the different [types of sample times here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/types-of-sample-time.html). A discrete sample time is the simple case, where the blocks are evaluated every t seconds. The block you have chosen only supports this kind of sample time.

To resolve the error, you must chose one of the two possibilities:

- Make the source signal discrete
- for the likely case that your source is continuous, choose the [continuous integral](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/integrator.html)

Comment: It was caused by the fact that I used a `discrete-time integrator`instead of a countinuous `integrator`.

Comment: Another hint: pay attention to the solver you are using.